# How can I constrain a <ul>'s width to the width of the widest item?

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup:

```
<ul>
   <li>apple</li>
   <li class="highlight">orange</li>
   <li>pear</li>
</ul>
```

Both the `ul`s and the `li`s widths appear to be 100%. If I apply a `background-color` to the list item, the highlight stretches the full width of the page.

I only want the background highlight to stretch as wide as the widest item (with maybe some padding). How do I constrain the `li`s (or perhaps the `ul`s) width to the width of the widest item?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't give the list a specified width?

Comment: I want to avoid unnecessarily wrapping long list items.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding `ul {float: left; }` style will force your list into preferred width, which is what you want.

Problem is, you should make sure next element goes below the list, as it did before. Clearing should take care of that.

Comment: any way then to center this list?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div for how to do that, but you should avoid `float` as the solution here anyway, even circa '08 or '11.

Answer (score 3):

Can you do it like this?

```
<ul>
   <li>apple</li>
   <li><span class="highlight">orange</span></li>
   <li>pear</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as BoltBait said, wrap your text in an inline element, such as `span` and give that the class.

```
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li><span class="highlight">orange</span></li>
    <li>pear</li>
</ul>
```

My extra 2 cents is that if you don't have access to change the HTML, you can do it using Javascript. In jQuery:

```
$('li.highlight').wrapInner("<span></span>");
```

and use the CSS:

```
li.highlight span { background-color: #f0f; }
```

---

edit: after re-reading your question, can you clarify: do you want the highlight to only go as wide as the element which is highlighted, or as wide as the widest element in the list? eg:

```
    - short
    - items ********************
    - here
    - and then a really long one
```

...where the asterisks represent the highlighting. If so, then buti-oxa's answer is the easiest way. just be careful with clearing your floats.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `style="float: left;"` to `ul` will cause the `ul` to only stretch as wide as the widest item.  However, the next element will be placed to the right of it.  Adding `style="clear: left;"` to the next element will place the next element after the `ul`.

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/w07hn13s/)

See [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) on `float` and `clear`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of going about solving this without messing up the style of your existing layout, is by wrapping the `ul` and `li` in a `div` with `display: inline-block`

```
   <div id='dropdown_tab' style='display: inline-block'>dropdown
        <ul id='dropdown_menu' style='display: none'>
            <li>optoin 1</li>
            <li>optoin 2</li>
            <li id='option_3'>optoin 3
                <ul id='dropdown_menu2' style='display: none'>
                    <li>second 1</li>
                    <li>second 2</li>
                    <li>second 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the existing answers provide the correct solution, unfortunately. They range from abusing the `float` property to totally restructuring your HTML, something which often isn't feasible.

The [`<ul>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/ul.html#ul-display) element has `display: block;` as its default [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-block) property, causing the width to fill 100% of its container.

To change this aspect and still retain all the other default properties of how a `<ul>` is displayed (e.g. avoid issues with `float` from other answers), apply `display: inline-block;` to the list:

```css
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: orange; /* for demonstration */
    padding: 15px; /* for demonstration */
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>apple</li>
   <li class="highlight">orange</li>
   <li>pear</li>
   <li>banana</li>
</ul>
```