# How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?

Tags: css, xhtml, menuitem

I need to center align a horizontal menu.
I've tried various solutions, including the mix of `inline-block` / `block` / `center-align` etc., but haven't succeeded.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="topmenu-design">
    <!-- Top menu content: START -->
    <ul id="topmenu firstlevel">                                                                                       
      <li class="firstli" id="node_id_64"><div><a href="#"><span>Om kampanjen</span></a></div></li>
      <li id="node_id_65"><div><a href="#"><span>Fakta om inneklima</span></a></div></li>
      <li class="lastli" id="node_id_66"><div><a href="#"><span>Statistikk</span></a></div></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Top menu content: END -->
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I know how to center align the `ul` within the `div`. That can be accomplished using Sarfraz's suggestion.
But the list items are still floated left within the `ul`.

Do I need Javascript to accomplish this?

Comment: Center the text in each LI or center the UL within the DIV?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

From http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm:

> The premise is simple and basically just involves a widthless float wrapper that is floated to the left and then shifted off screen to the left width position:relative; left:-50%. Next the nested inner element is reversed and a relative position of +50% is applied. This has the effect of placing the element dead in the center. Relative positioning maintains the flow and allows other content to flow underneath.

### Code

```css
#buttons{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    text-align:left;
}
#buttons ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}

#buttons li{float:left;position:relative;}/* ie needs position:relative here*/

#buttons a{
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:10px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    border:2px outset blue;
    color:#fff;
    padding:2px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#buttons a:hover{ border:2px inset blue;color:red;background:#f2f2f2;}
#content{overflow:hidden}/* hide horizontal scrollbar*/
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Button 2's a bit longer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Butt 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some code or context to this answer to prevent link rot?

Comment: The solution works great and I'm sorry to ask this after such a long time, but what if I have a css drop down? I can't use overflow:hidden in the parent then. But it'll still overflow like here: http://homeafrika.com .

Comment: Don't actually see any overflow on that site.  I'm not sure you need the overflow: hidden; bit anyways, though since it's for horizontal overflow, you could always try overflow-x: hidden; instead.  http://webchat.freenode.net/?nick=oerflowono&channels=#websites for real-time assistance.

Comment: The solution centers the menu nicely, but if you have submenus that should open at a certain fixed position on hover, you're doomed since the `position: relative` of the main menu changes the behavior of the `position:absolute` of the sub menu.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still quite hard to know what you're talking about.  If you can't IRC, I'd be happy to address a separate question you might create if you link to it from here.

Comment: @reisio Where there is `#buttons` id in OP's question? Where there is notice, in your answer, that he have to use it? How can this be accepted and top-voted answer, if you're actually **not** answering the question, only citing some off-topic blah-blah from some link?

Comment: @trejder: Don't know, don't care; but it does answer the question, so that's probably why it was accepted and upvoted.

Comment: Have you noticed that your grouping is not centered in the container?

Comment: @Robusto I'm not sure what random editors have added to this answer. Stick with the original link and you should be good, although this approach is probably a little more work than you should bother with these days.

Answer (score 94):

This works for me. If I haven't misconstrued your question, you might give it a try.

```css
    div#centerDiv {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    ul.centerUL {
        margin: 2px auto;
        line-height: 1.4;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .centerUL li {
        display: inline;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="centerDiv">
    <ul class="centerUL">
        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: agree with @cweiske. Simply using a text-align: center on the containing div solved the issue for me

Comment: You'll just need to make sure any text inside gets a `text-align: left;`

Comment: This is lovely! But, the ul has default padding on the left which means the menu is nudged to the right of the center. You'll need to remove the default padding from the ul with padding-left: 0;

Comment: Perfectly a better answer than the accepted solution, use of display:inline does the trick. do not use float, its overly complicated. Thanks for the insights @Robusto

Comment: text-align center in li is unnecessary

Comment: I added `display:inline-block;` on `.centerUL li` and works fine for me.

Answer (score 84):

With CSS3 flexbox. Simple.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend this method

Comment: I too would recommend this method over the chosen answer.

Comment: I would have to say I have never ever used flex before neither justify-content. Excellent answer

Comment: `justify-content: center;` is what's needed to fix the problem.

Comment: Add flex-wrap:wrap so it can go multi-lines for mobile resolution

Answer (score 20):

This is the simplest way I found. I used your html. The padding is just to reset browser defaults.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topmenu-design">
  <!-- Top menu content: START -->
  <ul id="topmenu firstlevel">
    <li class="firstli" id="node_id_64">
      <div><a href="#"><span>Om kampanjen</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="node_id_65">
      <div><a href="#"><span>Fakta om inneklima</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="lastli" id="node_id_66">
      <div><a href="#"><span>Statistikk</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Top menu content: END -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a good article on how to do it in a pretty rock-solid way, without any hacks and full cross-browser support. Works for me:

--> http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

Comment: Can you post a summary of this just in case the link goes down?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
div.topmenu-design ul
{
  display:block;
  width:600px; /* or whatever width value */
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: That works to center the UL. But the <LI> is still float left. I want the <LI> to be centered inside the <UL>. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this :

```
   <div id="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/1.html">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2.html">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/3.html">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/4.html">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/5.html">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#footer {
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:39px;
    line-height:36px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:950px;
}

#footer ul li {
    display:inline;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    padding:0 2px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so many of you, I've been struggling with this for a while.  The solution ultimately had to do with the div containing the UL. All suggestions on altering padding, width, etc. of the UL had no effect, but the following did.

It's all about the **`margin:0 auto;`** on the containing div.  I hope this helps some people, and thanks to everyone else who already suggested this in combination with other things.

```
.divNav
{
    width: 99%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto; 
}

.divNav ul
{ 
    display:inline-block; 
    list-style:none;
    zoom: 1;
}

.divNav ul li 
{
    float:left;
    margin-right: .8em;       
    padding: 0; 
}

.divNav a,  #divNav a:visited
{
    width: 7.5em;
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:none;
    padding: 5px; 
    background-color:#F90;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Demo - http://codepen.io/grantex/pen/InLmJ

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Others</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


.navigation {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Omg so much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the way to center a black level element (like a `<ul>`) is using the `margin:auto;` property.

To align text and inline level elements within a block level element use `text-align:center;`. So all together something like...

```
ul {
    margin:auto;
}
ul li {
    text-align:center;
    list-style-position:inside; /* so that the bullet points are also centered */
}
ul li div {
    display:inline; /* so that the bullet points aren't above the content */
}
```

... should work.

The fringe case is Internet Explorer6... or even other IEs when not using a `<!DOCTYPE>`. IE6 incorrectly aligns block level elemnts using `text-align`. So if you're looking to support IE6 (or not using a `<!DOCTYPE>`) your full solution is...

```
div.topmenu-design {
    text-align:center;
}
div.topmenu-design ul {
    margin:auto;
}
div.topmenu-design ul li {
    text-align:center;
    list-style-position:inside; /* so that the bullet points are also centered */
}
div.topmenu-design ul li div {
    display:inline; /* so that the bullet points aren't above the content */
}
```

As a footnote, I think `id="topmenu firstlevel"` is invalid as an `id` attribute can't contain spaces... ? Indeed the [w3c recommendation defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) the `id` attribute as a ['name' type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)...

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Answer (score 1):

I used the display:inline-block property: the solution consist in use a wrapper with fixed width. Inside, the ul block with the inline-block for display. Using this, the ul just take the width for the real content! and finally margin: 0 auto, to center this inline-block =)

```
/*ul wrapper*/
.gallery_wrapper{
        width:          958px;
        margin:         0 auto;
  }
/*ul list*/
ul.gallery_carrousel{
        display:        inline-block;
        margin:         0 auto;
}
.contenido_secundario li{
        float:          left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Robusto's solution was the simplest for what I was trying to do, I suggest you use it.  I was trying to do the same thing for images in an unordered list to make a gallery... I made a js fiddle to fool around with it.  Feel free to [try it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xanderoid/6wCHZ)

[it was set up using robusto's sample code]
HTML:

```
<div id="centerDiv">
    <ul class="centerUL">
        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150>         </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#centerDiv {
    width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
ul.centerUL {
    margin: 2px auto;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.centerUL li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use jquery code for this. (Alternative solution)

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
       var margin = $(".topmenu-design").width()-$("#topmenu").width();
       $("#topmenu").css('margin-left',margin/2);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
     text-align: center;
}
div ul {
     display: inline-table;
}
```

ul as inline-table fixes the with issue. I used the parent div to align the text to center.
this way it looks good even in other languages (translation, different width)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{margin-left:33%}
```

Is a decent approximation on big screens.  Its not good, but a good dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just setting the `li` item's `display` property to `inline-flex`:

```css
li {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

You may choose to add `justify-content: center` to the `li`s, and `padding: 0` to the `ul` to straighten things out.

Answer (score -2):

```
.topmenu-design
{
    display: inline-table;
}
```

That all!