# How to display wrapping flex items as space-between with last row aligned left?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a fixed-width container into which several variable-width elements must appear in a row, which can spill over into additional rows as necessary.

However, the beginning of each element must be aligned with the one on top of it, so in ASCII art it would look like so (say, padding of 1):

```
    /----------------------------------\
    |                                  |
    | # One    # Two   # Three  # Four |
    | # Five   # Six                   |
    |                                  |
    \----------------------------------/
```

In other words:

- The first element of every row must be left-aligned
- The last element of every row (except for the final row) must be right-aligned
- Every element must be left-aligned to the element above it

I'm trying to use flexbox for this without success.

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeOLVK) is the best I've come so far, using `flex-wrap: wrap` for the container and `flex-grow: 1` for the elements.

Problem is that the last row fills out to the edge.

```
justify-content: flex-start; // this does nothing
```

If I take away `flow-grow: 1` then the elements aren't distributed equally. I also tried fiddling around with `last-of-type` on the elements but it's also not enough.

Is this even possible with `flexbox`, or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Related? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266993/justify-divs-left-in-parent/34267611#34267611

Comment: Maybe with CSS grid?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After trying the suggestions here (thanks!) and searching the web long and wide, I've reached the conclusion that this is simply not possible with flexbox. And by that I mean that others have reached this conclusion while I stubbornly tried to make it work anyway, until finally giving up and accepting the wisdom of wiser people.

There are a couple of links I came across that might explain it better, or different aspects of the requirements, so I'm posting them here for... posterity.

[How to keep wrapped flex-items the same width as the elements on the previous row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274338/how-to-keep-wrapped-flex-items-the-same-width-as-the-elements-on-the-previous-ro)

http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/responsive-multi-column-lists-flexbox

Comment: The posted solution by Jonas Lundman seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 25):

There is no easy way to do this with flexbox. But if you are willing to sacrifice IE then you can do it with css `grid`, add this to the container:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
```

And if you want to have some space between the elements then add

```
grid-gap: 10px;
```

Answer (score 15):

I know I am kind of late, but I have been looking for solution for this in past hour or so, and I think I sort of figured it out. Put empty `div` on the end of your container, and set `flex-grow: 1` to it, and nothing else. Also set `justify-content: space-between` on container, and don't use `flex-grow` on other items. This will always make last line align left because this div will stretch through all remaining space.

However the problem of this is that it ALWAYS makes last line align left - even if it is the only line, which makes this solution unusable for me, but it might be usable for someone who can expect more than one line of items.

Comment: This is a good idea but unfortunately the spacing with this method is not equel between lines :'(

Answer (score 4):

If the width of your items is fixed, you can add several empty divs to the end of your list of items:

```
<div class="item">meaningful content</div>
<div class="item">meaningful content</div>
<div class="item">meaningful content</div>

<div class="empty-div"></div>
<div class="empty-div"></div>
<div class="empty-div"></div>
```

and then:

```
.item, .empty-div{ width: 150px; } // make them the same width
```

Works perfectly well.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question, but it answers mine :)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve the desired result with a combination of positive and negative margins.

If each element in the container defines a margin to create a space between them:

```
.container .element {
   flex: 1;
   margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

recover the pixels from the edges of each row in the container with a negative margin of the same amount:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin: 0px -5px;
}
```

This should result in 10px between each element in the row with the first and last of each row at the edge of the container.

Comment: This is a good solution for making the space between work when wrapping.

However, this answer ultimately does not answer the question.  The poster is looking for the last row to be left aligned with boxes of the same size as other rows.

Comment: Or use `gap`


https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox

Answer (score 4):

One solution that will work in many cases is simply applying `padding` to the items. Then you can use `flex-start`, and get spacing in between the cards.

For example

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
  width: 420px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 30%;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="child-content">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <div class="child-content">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <div class="child-content">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="child">
      <div class="child-content">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="child">
      <div class="child-content">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS Flex 4 columns always starting at left. I **cant see wy** this is impossible? If the columns should be *equal in with*, this **working for us** using `calc()` and relative units:

```
/* parent */

.ua-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: start;
}

/* children */

.ua-flex > * {
    flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 1em);
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}
.ua-flex > :not(:nth-child(4n+4)) {
    margin-right: 1.333333em;
}
```

Im I missing something here? Its all abouth math, the subtracted calc() in this case 1em, gives 3 space of gap 1.333em with margin-right on 3 of 4 columns, and 0.5em subtracted calc() should give 0.666em gap with margin-right on 3 of 4 columns.

Hope this can be useful...

Comment: This solution works, no padding or grids. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! works, i only needed to change the syntax of `.ua-flex > :not(:nth-child(4n+4)` to `.ua-flex:not(:nth-child(4n+4)`  to make that rule work too. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed with @ViktorBorítás this works with that minor change.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across the same problem and came up with another solution. I can't decide whether it feels kind of dirty or elegant, but decide for yourself.

Add as many empty `div`s as your maximum number of items per row to the container, assign them the same class as row items but remove any margin or padding from them (basically anything which gives them a height). That'll result in the row behaving as expected because after the last row item, there'll always be enough invisible "spacers" to pad the row. Those being wrapped to the next row have no height, so they shouldn't affect the rest of your page.

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/amknwjmj/

```css
.products {
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap:       wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.product {
    
  /* set top and bottom margin only, as left and right
     will be handled by space-between */
  margin: 0.25rem 0;

  /* account your desired margin two times and substract
     it from the base width of the row item */
  flex-basis: calc(25% - (0.25rem * 2));
}

.product.spacer {
      
  /* remove all properties increasing the element height 
     from the spacers to avoid them being visible */
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
  height:  initial;
}

/* start demo styles (purely eye-candy not required for this to work) */
* {
  box-sizing:  border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.products {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  background: powderblue;
}

.product {
  height:      75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding:     .25rem;
  text-align:  center;
  background:  steelblue;
  color:       #fff;
}  
  
.product.spacer {
  background: none;

  /* of course, spacers should NOT have a border
     but they are helpful to illstrate what's going on. */
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
/* end demo styles */
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <article id="product-1" class="product">P1</article>
  <article id="product-2" class="product">P2</article>
  <article id="product-3" class="product">P3</article>
  <article id="product-4" class="product">P4</article>

  <article id="product-5" class="product">P5</article>
  <div class="product spacer"></div>
  <div class="product spacer"></div>
  <div class="product spacer"></div>

  <div class="product spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you have a container and some stuff inside?

```
<div class="container">
  <span>msg1</span>
  <span>msg1</span>
  <span>msg1</span>
  <span>msg1</span>
  <span>msg1</span>
</div>
```

This is how it works, when you declare `display: flex` for your container all of its direct children will become flex too, with some default config (`align-items:strech`).

I guess you already got that, so, maybe you can try using `justify-content: space-between` which will align your items in the row leaving them equally spaced plus `flex-basis: 25%` (to certify that there will be always 4 items in a row, change de % as you wish) that is supposed to work for all your lines except the last one. For the last one you can use a css selector (like `last-child`) and set its property to `flex-grow: 0` / `flex-shrink:0` (solving one of your problems, if you used `flex: 1 1 25%` instead of `flex-basis`) and also `align-self: flex-start` or whatever you like

Comment: There are a couple of problems.. I'd like the first rows to behave as `justify-content: space-between` and the last row to behave like `justify-content: flex-start`. Also, the last element won't shrink or grow per your suggestion but it might not be alone in the row, and won't prevent the others from shrinking or growing (maybe related to the first point).

Comment: I don't know how many items, nor their width - it's dynamically loaded.

Comment: You will need a way to figure out which elements are inside your last row. You can try nested flexbox and aplying some logic to whatever you are using to dinamically load your stuff. Or you can use regular bootstrap columns (which will work just as fine) and flexbox only to align inside content,  sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Columns + inner flex might be the way to go, I'll give it a shot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a fixed-with-pseudo-element:

```
.container {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
.container .element {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can specify `margin-right` on every item except the last one in the row of flex-wrap by doing the following:

```
.item:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I was facing the same issue and in fact it's really simple. No need to put some 
SCSS and or jQuery.

You just need to specify a maximum number of "square", and make a modulo to know if that match with your maxNumber. If its not, you just have to define a quick function that increment your number until that modulo return 0.

When you have your number you just have to loop your html.
For me I was coding on ReactNative:

```
const RenderInvisibleSquare = (nb) => {
 let tab = [];
 let i = 1;
 for (; (nb + i) % 3 !== 0; i++) {}
 for (let n = 0; n < i; n++) {
  tab.push(<View style={{ width: 120, height: 120, backgroundColor: 'red' }}/>);
 }
 return tab;
};


<ScrollView>
  {
    data.map(item => (
      <View>
        <View style={{ marginVertical: 5 }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: '#7E8BF5' }}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          {
            item.data.map(elem => (
              <View style={{ width: 120, height: 120, marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
            ))
          }
          { item.data.length % 3 !== 0 && RenderInvisibleSquare(item.data.length)}
        </View>
      </View>
    ))
  }
</ScrollView>
```

If you dont want content (backgroundColor: 'red') in my case you juste have to make it 'transparent'.

Comment: "no need to use SCSS or [jQuery]" but you need to use React? Not really useful for a CSS question...