# CSS Flexbox/Grid dynamic columns and gaps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have dynamic container, it width is 319px and can be smaller. I want to display inside of it for example images. Item (image) width is static, 80px. Using Flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap` and `justify-content: space-between`. If in row 3 items, first column at left side, last column in right side, and gap between columns is okay for me. When in second row only two columns, gap between them is too big for me. I want to have same columns gap like first row. If width is smaller and Flexbox can contain only 2 items, and gap is bigger - it is okay for me. I just want to render few rows with same gaps between columns.

I can't normally explain the problem, but `justify-content: space-between` is okay for me while number of items per rows is same and container width filled 100%.
Static or calculated flexbox items width is not suitable for me because images have static width and I can't know how many items can fit into a container and first item and last row item must be near the container boundary (except when first row have more items then second).

[image: Flexbox image]

```css
.container {
  max-width: 319px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px dotted black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color: grey;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color: #dadada;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color: gold;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color: #CD7F32;"></div>
</div>
```

What is the best practice?

P.S: Using Grid looks nice, but it adding gaps from sides. Is it possible to remove it?

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 8px;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

[image: Grid image]

Answer (score -2):

This isn't really possible with flexbox. See [This Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331102/how-to-display-wrapping-flex-items-as-space-between-with-last-row-aligned-left)
As a workaround, you could use `justify-content:start;` and add a `margin-right` to the items.