# Editing Nav Menu - How Do I Wrap display:block, float:left to have a Centered Menu?

Tags: css, wrapper, center, navbar

Right, so, I've been self-editing a rather complicated site and have been stuck on this last part involving the menu. It has a float:left command (the navbar displays alined to the left of the screen) and I've been trying to get it to text-align:center (appear centered within the screen) with a wrapper but have been unsuccessful.

Below is the coding:

```
#nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Droid Serif", Georgia ,serif;
}
#nav > .current-menu-item > a,
#nav > li a:hover { color: #4C4C4C }
.plus { color: #aaa }
#nav ul {
    position: center;
    display: none;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#nav li a {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 8px 15px;
```

I'm a programming noob and pretty much survive on combination of trial and error and the "inspect element" command in google chrome. Please be gentle and rather explanatory :)

cheers,
Jess

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the ul in the nav, just add **width** to ul and **margin: 0 auto;**
If you do not want to add a width check out [How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu)

Answer (score 0):

instead of **float** give **display:inline-block** to your LI . Write like this:

```
#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE*/
    *zoom:1;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```