# Advanced drop down menu not aligning to middle of page

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

Basically i have a dropdown menu that is not aligning to the middle of the page as you can see below... It is very annoying because i have tried everything i know possible. I would like to keep it in HTML and CSS please as this part i am not using JavaScript or JQuery to do.

**CSS Code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
/* TOP MENU DROP DOWN */
#menu li {
    color: #222222;
}
#mega {
list-style:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
#mega li {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
#mega li div div {
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
#mega li:hover {
border-bottom:0;
z-index:1;
    position:center;
}
#mega a {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
#mega a:hover {
    color:#077fcc;
}

#mega div {
    left:-999em;
}
#mega li:hover div {
    position:center;
    display:block;
    left:0;
}
a:hover, #mega div a:focus, #mega div a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-image:url(img/dropdownbg.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
.popup-mid {
    text-align:left;
    position:center;
    height:100%;
    width:950px;
}

/* TOP INSIDE*/

#top-dropbg {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
.drop-box {
    margin:30px 15px;
    height:240px;
}
.drop-sec1 {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    height:240px;
    width:70%;
}
.drop-sec1-1 {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
.drop-sec1-2 {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    width:25%;
    height:95px;
}
.drop-sec1-3 {
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #CCC;
}
.drop-sec2 {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    height:240px;
    width:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
}
.drop-sec3 {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    height:240px;
    width:25%;
}
/* END TOP MENU */

h1 {
    color:#858585;
    font-size:14px;
}
h2{
    color:#333333;
    font-size:24px;
}
p {
    color:#333333;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
        <div class="navtop">
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul id="mega">
                        <li><a href="#">Bookings</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            <span id="top-dropbg">
                                <span class="drop-box">
                                    <span class="drop-sec1">
        <span class="drop-sec1-1"><h2>Our Services</h2></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-3"></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
        <span class="drop-sec1-2"><h1>Vehicles for Every Pocket</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue.</p></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="drop-sec2">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="drop-sec3">
        <span class="drop-sec3-1"><h1>Membership and Reward Schemes</h1><p>Lorem ipsum etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue donec congue lacinia dui.</p></span>
                                    </span>
</span>
</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Explore Our Fleet</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            2
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rental Locator</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            3
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            4
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            5
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Specials</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            6
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bluechip</a>
                            <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-mid">
                            7
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you in advance all :)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in style

```
body
{ 
text-align: center; /* !!! */
 margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
}
```

and change this

```
#mega li {
float:left;
clear:right;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

to

```
#mega li {
display:inline;
clear:right;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```