# Split Menu in Wordpress via css and reorder right side section

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing the following.

Basically, I have a standard horizontal main menu being outputted by Wordpress. What I want to do is float half to the left and half to the right and put a logo in the middle. To do this I attached a custom class (via the wordpress menu panel) to each li as the below.

```
    .menu-li-left {
    float: left;
    }

   .menu-li-right {
    float: right;
    }
```

However, the right side is of course in reverse order. To fudge it I have tested using something like "right: -9% and right: 9%" to reorder each menu item (I only have 3 menu items on the right side). It seems to work and it is even responsive, but this isn't very elegant.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution via CSS that I should try or is this not possible from CSS alone?

Thanks

Comment: You are in control of the menu order in wordpress. Why not just reverse the last 3 in the menu editor?

Comment: It's a responsive site. That would reverse the order for tablets and mobile phones as well. For mobile devices it changes to the boostrap like dropdown. It's a theme based on bootstrap.

Comment: You also could just make a mobile menu

Comment: I would add the logo to the menu. Give it an extra css class the give it a different look. That way you could make all links center to create a consistent look on both sides

Comment: Hey Janw, that is an interesting idea. I could add the the logo in a li in the middle and then add padding to the left and right to space out as needed. I will need to see if I can do it by using how Wordpress outputs menus.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I thought the best solution, was simply to add custom classes for padding to the li elements to the left and right of the image. Pretty simple. I was stuck thinking of just floating li's to the left and right.

For positioning the UL in the center that contains floating elements, the below post was very helpful.

[How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu)