# Can't center the UL tag

Tags: html, css

How can I center this `ul` tag ?

I tried every thing I know but nothing works (http://jsfiddle.net/alhasen/dmW5F/).

Note: View this in fullscreen.

See this `ul` list at the center of the fieldset.

```
 <ul id="progressbar">
   <li class="active">First step</li>
   <li>Second step</li>
   <li>Third step</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu)

Comment: you could use `display:inline-block;` on `#progressbar` and use `display:block` for all floated child li's this will center it but you will have to adjust the styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted to see but take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dmW5F/1/

Anyway what I did was

remove the `ul {width:1000px}` resulting to:

```
    ul {
        margin: auto auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
```

and changed `#progressbar li` to:

```
    #progressbar li {
        list-style-type:none;
        color:#fff;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-size:9px;
        width:30%;
        padding-top:10px;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative
    }
```

I removed the `float:left`, added `display:inline-block`, changed `width` to `width:30%`

Tell me if you have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: 1 more question , the animation on the fieldset changing (when click the next and prev buttons)
can i remove it ? :(

Comment: I dont see any visible next and prev buttons? But I do see them inside `fieldset#frame2`

Comment: if your using a plugin and the animations are made by the plugin then I would suggest you take a look at the documentation of the plugin (if there is an existing one). The developer might have added a no-animation feature that you just need to implement.

Comment: its not a plugin , i made it according to this tutorial
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Comment: i dont want to remove the whole animation , just the scaling

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="centered">
    <ul id="progressbar">
         <li class="active">First step</li>
         <li>Second step</li>
         <li>Third step</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#progressbar {
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#progressbar li {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 30%;
}
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/gNM3g/)