# How do I center my navigation bar on my website?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to create a navigation bar on my website for a project. I get the bar just fine, but I can't get it to center on the page. I have tried a variety of different methods. Can someone help me out? I'm using an external style sheet. Here is the code for my main page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tylerschevy.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tyler Chevrolet</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="showRoom.html">Show Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.chevrolet.com">Official Site</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my style sheet:

```
h1 {text-align:center}
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    background-color:#FFFF33;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active{
    background-color:#0033FF;
    color:white;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZeMX/)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu

Answer (score 3):

Add `class="nav"` to your `<ul>`, and then in your stylesheet create a new class:

```
.nav {
display: table; margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhW7A/)

Answer (score 0):

Center ul

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}

ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I recommend to put your ul in one wrapper (so you don't touch the body) like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
    text-align:center;
}

ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```