# How do I center this CSS menu?

Tags: css

I have a CSS menu here that works fine, honestly. The only thing I want to change about it is the location of the tabs. They all start at the left of the page, while I'd rather have them centered at the middle. `margin: auto;` did not help me in this case. Can anyone look into this for me please?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWrRVO

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current list items float to left which is making it start from left of the menu. Reset them to none and use `display: inline-block` to align them in a line.

```css
#cssmenu li {
  float: none; /* Modify */
  display: inline-block; /* Add */
  padding: 0px;
}
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOxLwG)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I'll choose your answer as the solution as soon as I'm able to! Thank you a million times! :D

Comment: Haha! :) Glad that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin in `UL` to margin auto. Put the background in `#cssmennu`.
CSS

```
#cssmenu {
 position:relative;
 border: none;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #333333;
 padding: 0px;
 font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 width: auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#cssmenu ul {
background: #333333;
height: 35px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width:1000px;
}
```

Check This **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdVMqN)**

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
#cssmenu {text-align: center;}
#cssmenu ul {display: inline-block;}
```