# Centering responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making responsive horizontal menu that fades in background while scrolling down (using jQuery to implement that).

So I was trying to center my menu and I've failed, I've used `width: 50%;` in ul element in css but it doesn't centering the menu.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet Ms';
}

.bg {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.transition {    
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  height: 200px;
  margin: -70px 0 0;
  width: 50%;
}

li {
  direction: rtl;
  float: right; 
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #000;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #949494;

  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  color: #a6a6a6;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #C9C9C9;
}

.down {
  top: 150px;
}

.up {
  top: 1800px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="container">

            <div class="fixed">

              <div class="bg transition"></div>

              <ul>
                <li>אודות</li>
                <li>למה אנחנו?</li>
                <li>What To Eat</li>
                <li>צור קשר</li>
                <li>Get App</li>
              </ul>

            </div>

            <a href="#bottom" class="scroll down">SCROLL DOWN</a>
            <a href="#top" id="bottom" class="scroll up">SCROLL UP</a>

          </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz61tam2/2/)

How can I center my menu in a responsive way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flex on ul with justify-content:center

From

```
ul {
  height: 200px;
  margin: -70px 0 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

To

```
ul {
  height: 200px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mz61tam2/3/

Answer (score 1):

There is not yet any specific styling for centering elements. Try

margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I have already tried this, but it doesn't work. Some thing prevent the auto margin work properly

Comment: It's working for me in your JS Fiddle, so I'm not sure what part isn't the way you're trying to get it. I put the margin auto on the ul element. Because the width is at 50%, some of of your li elements may drop down to the line below, but you can fix this by increasing the width of your ul. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use Flexbox to center items. Make the containing div display: flex and then you can justify and align the content to the center. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `text-align:center;` in parent, and `margin:0 auto;` for UL menu.

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
text-align:center;
}

ul {
  height: 200px;
  margin: -70px auto 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: still not working, it heading right more than center