# center ul li images in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center ul and li images but it's not happening I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div) but this isn't working for me.

I want to center the unordered list and it's list item

HTML

```
<div class="brands">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/flipkart.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/ola.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/olx.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/telenor.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/uc.png"></li>
    <li><img src="images/oyo.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.brands {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.brands ul {
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.brands li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.brands img {
  padding: 35px 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give `float: left`, it will never be considered as an `inline` element. Use `display: inline-block` to make it an `inline` element with `block`'s properties to center it using `text-align: center`:

```css
.brands li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.brands ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: yes I was going to that but I have to wait for 9 minutes, thanks anyway

Comment: "If you give float: left, it will never be considered as an inline element", I understood float and inline-block that way first time.. thankx