# Centering links within navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I'm buidling my site and I'm trying to horizontal centering the following code with no luck: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZZJrK

If I'm not wrong I must add a css code for `nav ul` so I added the following code but it's not working:

```
nav ul li {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Can someone please tell me how can I center the menu so I can have the following output? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Hi..you want the navbar should be in horizontal center??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal li menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div)

Comment: [Centering a navigation menu](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=centering+a+navigation+menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `float: left` property from **`nav ul li`** and **`nav li`**
2. Change `display:block` to `display: inline-block` for **`li`**
3. Add the following to your css:

---

```
#nav ul {
  text-align:center;
}
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKKPGO

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: table;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to your `nav` like this:

```
nav {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/oLLPRg)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
        ul{
text-align:center;}
        li{
display: inline-block;
        float:none;
        text-align:center;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working (I tried using the link of the post). I added the code you post, and also changing the `li` to `nav li` but it's not working either.

Comment: you have 2 classes who have float left, and wrong displays (line 116 and 123). The forked codepen http://codepen.io/capitanflamingo/pen/mEEGgr

Answer (score 1):

I think all you really need is `text-align:center` on the parent element of the items/links/buttons

```css
#container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Because the ul tag is a block level element it will stretch the full width of the parent element

More info: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)