# Can't center a ul

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my ul, but I can't seem to get it to center. I have tried using `display: table margin: 0 auto` That puts the ul in the middle, but not exactly in the center. I have also tried using `display: block` with `margin: 0 auto` but that doesn't center it either

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

header {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Droplet Games - Official Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-index.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <h1>DROPLET GAMES</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center <ul> <li> into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div) and a multitude of similar answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this rule to the `<ul>`:

`display: inline-block;`

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

header {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Droplet Games - Official Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-index.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <h1>DROPLET GAMES</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
</html>
```

Comment: that's a workaround to the core problem, which is the `li` elements are `float-left`....

Comment: Yes I know, but I try to follow his code. I would not do it like that.

Comment: This does not work for me where I have <ul> under a <h[1-5]> element.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the issue isn't so much that you want the `ul` element centered, but rather you want the menu items (the `li` items) *inside* the `ul` to be centered.

The entire issue is solved by simply changing the style on your `li` from `float:left` to `display:inline-block`.  See below.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

header {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Droplet Games - Official Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-index.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <h1>DROPLET GAMES</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer: use flexbox

For the best control over spacing of elements in a column or a row, I'd recommend using flexbox now that it has widespread browser support.

To use flexbox here, set `display: flex;` on the `ul`, making it the *flex container*. By default, this will make the `ul` act as a *row* with the `li` acting as  *flex items* within that row. [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has a great guide about using flexbox.

I've left my original answer which uses `display: inline-block;` below.

### Original answer

Sounds like [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values) is exactly what you need.

As the name alludes, an element with `display: inline-block;` acts as if it's an `inline` element as far as its parent is concerned, and internally it acts like a `block` element.

Its use here requires a container with `width: 100%;` and `text-align: center;`. I've used the `<nav>` element below. The `<ul>` can then be given `display: inline-block;` to achieve the effect you want.

You can also use `display: inline-block;` in combination with `display: inline;` for the `<li>` and their child `<a>` elements as follows, in order to avoid the `float: left;` use.

```
li {
  display: inline;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>DROPLET GAMES</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">Games</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` as a wrapper around `float:left` elements feels wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: @cale_b A little, yeah. I try to avoid `float` altogether.

Comment: ```display:inline-block``` only lays out the <li> horizontally. I need them to be vertical and be centered underneath a h element.

Comment: @Harlin For better control over spacing of elements in a column or a row, I'd recommend using Flexbox. [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has a great guide about it.