# How do I center a <ul> element?

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question regarding some code i have here:

```
h1 {
    font - size: 65 px;
    color: orange;
    text - align: center;
    height: 20 px;
    font: Times;
}

h2 {
    text - align: center;
    font: Times;
}

ul {
    width: 1230 px;
    list - style - type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background - color: #C2C6DD;
    justify - content: center;
}
```

the `h1` and `h2` is the title of the webpage, which is centered.
However th ul (navigation bar) is not centered I have tried many different tings like align-items, text-align, it always goes to the left of the page. Anybody can help to why?

[image]

Comment: Very poor title. Edit to describe your actual issue.

Comment: You probably need to reset the default `padding` for `ul` elements as well.

Comment: Also, when asking about CSS issues it would be good to show your HTML code too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center <ul> <li> into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div)

Answer (score 0):

You try this code:

```
 ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C2C6DD;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin: 0 auto;` to the ul:

```
ul {
    width: 1230px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #C2C6DD;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
ul {
    width: 1230 px;
    list - style - type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background - color: #C2C6DD;
    justify - content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```