# Centering a link in a div

Tags: html, css

I have tried all the other ideas on stack Overflow, and nothing is working for me - so I'm starting to think i'm missing something silly. All I am trying to do is center a link tag in a div tag. I have tried doing right and left auto margins, as well as text align etc. Do you see an error I have overlooked? The links are inside a div with the id of header.

```css
#header a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try make the problem in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: or try to add screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that ul has its own ideas about aligning elements. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div) on centering ul withing div.

To get rid of the default padding and margin of the ul tag, try:

```
#menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then, if you would like to display the links next to each other horizontally, you have to alter the default behaviour of the li tags, for example as following:

```
.menuItem {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16892440)

Comment: Thank you Nikolaj, duly noted and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this -

```css
#header a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is another solution may it will helps you-

```css
#header a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
ul li {
    max-width: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display block like the following.

```
#header a{display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your CSS is for, but to center the link all you need is `text-align: center` for the list.

```css
#header a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menuItem"> <a href="home.html">Home</a> </li>
  <li class="menuItem"> <a href="music.html">Music</a> </li>
  <li class="menuItem"> <a href="services.=html">Services</a> </li>
  <li class="menuItem"> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
  <li class="menuItem"> <a href="bio.html">Bio</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 #menu li { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

set `text-align:center` to the parent

```
#menu li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
#menu li {
 text-align: center;
}
#menu a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 75px;
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css,

```
.menuItem {
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  list-style-type:none;
}
#header a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 75px; 
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run Below Code and Your Answer in ready

```css
ul#menu{text-align: center;list-style:none;}

ul#menu li a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

*IF you want items be horizontaly, use this code :*

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
#header a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*IF you want items be vertically, just use this code :*

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
#header a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should know that "a" tag has "inline--block" behavior
that means you should treat it like a text or image
text simply come in center with "text-align : center"

```css
ul,li {
  padding: inherit; 
}   
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}
#header a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 75px;       
}
```

```html
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="services.=html">Services</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
    </ul>
```