# How can I center a 'ul'?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center a ul for mobiles. This is my HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-active">Fruits</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-inactive">Veggies</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS code:

```css
.nav-items {
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   font-weight: normal;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   margin-right: 30px;
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And I kept a media query for phones:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .nav-items {
       margin: auto;
   }
}
```

How can I make the ul center (for phones)?

This is what I actually wanted:

[image]

Comment: What do you want exactly do you want to display item in top of the `ul`, item in the middle , item at the end or you just wants all of `li` to be centered at the middle of `ul` or you want the `ul` as overlay add some cleatify to your question there's a lot of valid answers but you don't accept anyone because you are not clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### File *style.css*

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav-items {
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}

.sub-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

}
```

#### File *index.html*

```
<ul class="nav-items">
    <ul class="sub-items">
    <li class="nav-active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-active">Fruits</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-inactive">Veggies</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted home and fruits in one row, and veggies in another row.

Comment: i have edited my code above use that. i have created the sublist inside the list. and also add some margin as you want.

Comment: Obviously, I would : )

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS code:

```css
nav{
   text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it:

Text align method (based on *[How can I center <ul> <li> into a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/how-can-i-center-ul-li-into-a-div/12185538#12185538)*):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav-items {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav-items>li>ul {
        display: inline-table;
    }
    .nav-items>li {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Using Flexbox: Look at [boris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68420483/how-to-center-a-ul/68420511#68420511).

Comment: text-align: center; didn't work for me, boris answer worked, but wasn't the result I actually wanted.

Comment: @AbhirajshriWinsome make sure everything is inline if you need flexbox lemme edit it

Comment: I didn't understand, can you give me the code?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .nav-items {
       margin: auto; display: inline !important;
   }
}`

Comment: It's the exact code that I gave in the question.

Comment: But the ul is stretching :(

Comment: I wanted 2 ul's in a row, and another ul in the second row. Both must be in the center.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235005/discussion-between-ragedcoder-and-abhirajshri-winsome).

Answer (score 1):

Something of this must be working. Try it:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-conten: center;
        align-content: center;
        align-items center;
        align-self: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a colon after "align-items"? Isn't "justify-conten" as misspelling? Both seem to be correct in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about the bulletins then you can go with `<center>` tag.

```
<nav>
  <center>
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-active">Fruits</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-inactive">Veggies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </center>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is replace `margin: auto` with `justify-content: space-between;`.

Here `margin: auto` haven't anything to do, because the element already takes the full width of the page. `margin: auto` is working when the element width is less than the page width while `justify-content: space-between;` will align the first element at first and the second element at the middle and third at the end.

**Here's your code:**

```css
.nav-items {
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   font-weight: normal;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   margin-right: 30px;
   margin-top: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .nav-items {
       justify-content: space-between;
   }
}
```

Also, if you want just to make the elements at the middle, you can use `justify-content: center;`, `align-items: center;`. That will make them at the middle of the `.nav-items`.

#### Example

```css
.nav-items {
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   font-weight: normal;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   margin-right: 30px;
   margin-top: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .nav-items {
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help. See the output below. I have given the output screenshot link below.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav-items {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .nav-items li:nth-of-type(3) {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

[See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZtcT.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, here is a suggestion to improve the post : you can add a language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Comment: More concrete: *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)*

Answer (score 1):

very simple and easy method because no forced width or parent div involved.

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>12345678910</li>
    <li>638023274</li>
    <li>12323145645</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .nav-items {
       margin: auto;
       flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

If you want the last item to be on a new line:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .nav-items {
        margin: auto;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .nav-items li{
        text-align: center;
    }

   .nav-items li:last-of-type{
        width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: But I want the first two li's to be in one row, and the last one in another row

Comment: Here the second one

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav style="text-align: center;" >
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;" >
        <li>google</li>
        <li>bing</li>
        <li>yahoo</li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68420585/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).